# Microsoft SQL Процедура получения количества товара на определенную сумму. Использование переменных после SELECT?

Tags: sql, запрос

Есть определенная сумма, нужно вычислить с помощью процедуры, какое количество товара можно за нее купить. Количество товара на складе ограничено, это тоже необходимо учитывать.

```
SELECT quantity, price FROM Goods WHERE ID=1;
```

1) Произвожу селект и получаю количество и цену товара с нужным ID. Как действовать дальше с полученными данными? Могу я использовать quantity, price как переменные и дальше производить операции с ними так же, как в языках программирования?

2) Для тестов создал конструкцию проверки случая, когда сумма позволяет купить весь товар, что бы в этом случае просто выводилось количество товара. Но конструкция не работает. В чем заключается ошибка?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
    begin
        IF((SELECT quantity * price FROM Goods WHERE ID=1;) < 1000) THEN
            SELECT quantity FROM Goods WHERE ID=1;
        END IF;
    end
```

Comment: да, вы можете использовать переменные https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017. Из ошибок - как минимум не нужна точка с запятой после первого запроса, так как он в скобках. Во вторых вы в заголовке написали что у вас Microsoft SQL, посмотрите синтаксис IF в нем https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/language-elements/else-if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 там нет никаких THEN и END IF. Вы почему то используете синтаксис похожий на MySQL. У каждой БД собственный, уникальный язык процедур

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Microsoft SQL. Процедура вывода максимального количества товаров за определенную сумму](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936768/microsoft-sql-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e)

Comment: Не задавайте один и тот же вопрос немного его перефразировав, лучше уточните в вопросе чего вы смогли добиться самостоятельно

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что похожий вопрос ТС уще задал.

Answer (score 0):

Синтаксис MySQL:

```
select 
  Name,
  price,
  @ByNow := IF(@MyCount/Price>cnt,cnt,TRUNCATE(@MyCount/price,0)) as Покупаем,
  cnt - @ByNow as Товаров_в_магазине_осталось,
  @MyCount:=@MyCount-Price*@ByNow as Остаток_денег
from 
  NAMES_01,
  (select @MyCount:=5000) c,
  (select @ByNow:=0) d
order 
  by price;
```

https://rextester.com/ZIZXLX48732